# Java How to implement lock on ConcurrentHashMap read

Tags: java, multithreading

TL;DR: in Java I have N threads, each using a shared collection. ConcurrentHashMap allows me to lock on write, but not on read. What I need is to lock a specific item of the collection, read the previous data, do some computation, and update the values. If two threads receive two messages from the same sender, the second thread has to wait for the first one to finish, before doing its stuff.

---

Long version:

These threads are receiving chronologically ordered messages, and they have to update the collection basing on a `messageSenderID`.

My code simplified is as follow:

```
public class Parent {
    private Map<String, MyObject> myObjects;

    ExecutorService executor;
    List<Future<?>> runnables = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();

    public Parent(){
        myObjects= new ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyObject>();

        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            WorkerThread worker = new WorkerThread("worker_" + i);
            Future<?> future = executor.submit(worker);
            runnables.add(future);
        }
    }

    private synchronized String getMessageFromSender(){
        // Get a message from the common source
    }

    private synchronized MyObject getMyObject(String id){
        MyObject myObject = myObjects.get(id);
        if (myObject == null) {
            myObject = new MyObject(id);
            myObjects.put(id, myObject);
        }
        return myObject;
    }

    private class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
        private String name;

        public WorkerThread(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(!isStopped()) {
                JSONObject message = getMessageFromSender();
                String id = message.getString("id");
                MyObject myObject = getMyObject(id);
                synchronized (myObject) {
                    doLotOfStuff(myObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I have one producer and N consumers, to speed-up processing, but the N consumers have to deal with a common base of data and chronological order has to be respected.

I am currently using a `ConcurrentHashMap`, but I'm willing to change it if needed.

The code seems to work if messages with same ID arrive enough apart (> 1 second), but if I get two messages with the same ID in the distance of microseconds, I get two threads dealing with the same item in the collection.

I *GUESS* that my desired behavior is:

```
Thread 1                        Thread 2
--------------------------------------------------------------
read message 1
find ID
lock that ID in collection
do computation and update
                                read message 2
                                find ID
                                lock that ID in collection
                                do computation and update
```

While I *THINK* that this is what happens:

```
Thread 1                        Thread 2
--------------------------------------------------------------
read message 1
                                read message 2
                                find ID
                                lock that ID in collection
                                do computation and update
find ID
lock that ID in collection
do computation and update
```

I thought about doing something like

```
JSONObject message = getMessageFromSender();
synchronized(message){
    String id = message.getString("id");
    MyObject myObject = getMyObject(id);
    synchronized (myObject) {
        doLotOfStuff(myObject);
    } // well maybe this inner synchronized is superfluous, at this point
}
```

But I think that would kill the whole purpose of having a multithreaded structure, since I would read one message at a time, and the workers are not doing anything else; and it would be like if I was using a SynchronizedHashMap instead of a ConcurrentHashMap.

---

For the record, I report here the solution I implemented eventually. I'm not sure it is optimal and I still have to test for performances, but at least the input is handed properly.

```
public class Parent implements Runnable {

    private final static int NUM_WORKERS = 10;
    ExecutorService executor;
    List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
    List<WorkerThread> workers = new ArrayList<WorkerThread>();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_WORKERS);
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++) {
            WorkerThread worker = new WorkerThread("worker_" + i);
            Future<?> future = executor.submit(worker);
            futures.add(future);
            workers.add(worker);
        }

        while(!isStopped()) {
            byte[] message = getMessageFromSender();
            byte[] id = getId(message);
            int n = Integer.valueOf(Byte.toString(id[id.length-1])) % NUM_WORKERS;
            if(n >= 0 && n <= (NUM_WORKERS-1)){
                workers.get(n).addToQueue(line);
            }
        }
    }

    private class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
        private String name;
        private Map<String, MyObject> myObjects;
        private LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]> queue;

        public WorkerThread(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void addToQueue(byte[] line) {
            queue.add(line);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(!isStopped()) {
                byte[] message= queue.poll();
                if(line != null) {
                    String id = getId(message);
                    MyObject myObject = getMyObject(id);
                    doLotOfStuff(myObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to make sure no two threads can modify the same `MyObject` instance concurrently?

Comment: Since the messages have a strict order, it's much simpler to just use a single thread to process them.  If you factor in locking and contention the single thread may even be faster.  Is the message processing so complex that a single thread will fall behind?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom yes, but if thread 2 has to modify the same object instance as thread 1, it has to wait for thread 1 to finish doing its job and updating the object's data. Otherwise they would read the same object's initial status, and thread 2 would end up overriding the computation done by thread 1.

Comment: @user949300 yes. I tested the single-thread and multi-thread version of my code. The single-thread version can handle 6-7k messages per minute, the multi-thread version can handle 20k. Of course my specs require a goal of 15k messages per minute.

Comment: @ocramot   With the need to preserve ordering your choices are limited.  See my answer for a way to get some speedup but probably not enough.  You may need to go to multiple HashMaps - for example, one handles all IDs starting with "A", another for " B", etc.  Then you can have 26 Threads running.  Would this be plausible for your application?

Comment: See my edited answer for multiple map idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually this is kind of routing problem. What you need to is:

Get your  your main thread (single thread) reading messages of the queue and push the data to a FIFO queue per id. 
Get a single thread to consume messages from each queue.

Locking examples will (probably) not work as after the second message order is not guaranteed even if `fair=true`.

From Javadoc:
`Even when this lock has been set to use a fair ordering policy, a call to tryLock() will immediately acquire the lock if it is available, whether or not other threads are currently waiting for the lock.`

One thing for you to decide is if you want to create a a thread per queue (which will exit once the queue is empty) or keep the fixed size thread pool and manage get the extra bits to assign threads to queues.

So, you get a single thread reading from the original queue and writing to the per-id-queues and the you also get one thread per id reading from individual queues. This will ensure task serialization.

In terms of performance, you should see significant speed-up as long as the incoming messages have a nice distribution (id-wise). If you get mostly same-id messages then task will be serialized and also include the overhead for control object creation and synchronization.

Comment: Basically what I said but expressed differently and perhaps better.

Comment: Hello, sorry if it took me so long to reply. Eventually, I ended up implementing a solution similar to what you proposed. So I keep going with the fixed threadpool, and I'm taking the last byte of the ID (which is an alphanumerical ASCII sequence) and I'm doing `thread_that_has_to_deal_with_this_message = last_byte_of_the_ID % number_of_parser_threads` . This is because unfortunately the IDs that I'm receiving are too numerous and of different types, and their structure and frequency of arrival is out of my control.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate `Map` for your locks. There's also a `WeakHashMap` that will automatically discard entries when the key is no longer present.

```
static final Map<String, Lock> locks = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<>());

public void lock(String id) throws InterruptedException {
    // Grab a Lock out of the map.
    Lock l = locks.computeIfAbsent(id, k -> new ReentrantLock());
    // Lock it.
    l.lockInterruptibly();
}

public void unlock(String id) throws InterruptedException {
    // Is it locked?
    Lock l = locks.get(id);
    if ( l != null ) {
        l.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: The above example, even though it is thread-safe, it does not preserve ordering. `computeIfAbsent` is going to create the lock atomically, however the actual `locking` is on the next line. A second thread can manage to acquire the lock first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea with your `synchronized` blocks, except you mis-analyze a bit and go too far in any case. The outer `synchronized` block shouldn't force you into dealing with only one message at a time, it just keeps multiple threads from accessing the *same message* at once. But you don't need it. You really only need that inner `synchronized` block, on the `MyObject` instance. That will ensure that only one thread at a time can access any given `MyObject` instance, while enabling other threads to access messages, the `Map` and other `MyObject` instances as much as they want.

```
JSONObject message = getMessageFromSender();
String id = message.getString("id");
MyObject myObject = getMyObject(id);
synchronized (myObject) {
    doLotOfStuff(myObject);
}
```

If you don't like that, and the updates to the `MyObject` instances all involve single-method invocations, then you could just `synchronize` all of those methods. You still retain concurrency in the `Map`, but you're protecting the `MyObject` itself from concurrent updates.

```
class MyObject {
  public synchronize void updateFoo() {
    // ...
  }

  public synchronize void updateBar() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

When any `Thread` accesses any `updateX()` method it will automatically lock out any other `Thread` from accessing that or any other `synchronized` method. That would be simplest, if your updates match that pattern.

If not, then you'll need to make all of your worker `Threads` cooperate by using some sort of locking protocol. The `ReentrantLock` that OldCurmudgeon suggests is a good choice, but I would put it on `MyObject` itself. To keep things ordered properly, you should use the *fairness* parameter (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#ReentrantLock-boolean-). "When set true, under contention, locks favor granting access to the longest-waiting thread."

```
class MyObject {
  private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

  public void lock() {
    lock.lock();
  }

  public void unlock() {
    lock.unlock();
  }

  public void updateFoo() {
    // ...
  }

  public void updateBar() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then you could update things like this:

```
JSONObject message = getMessageFromSender();
String id = message.getString("id");
MyObject myObject = getMyObject(id);
myObject.lock();
try {
    doLotOfStuff(myObject);
}
finally {
    myObject.unlock();
}
```

The important takeaway is that you don't need to control access to the messages, nor the `Map`. All you need to do is ensure that any given `MyObject` is being updated by at most one thread at a time.

Comment: I think you potentially lose the ordering of messages with this.

Comment: You say that "If two threads receive two messages from the same sender, the second thread has to wait for the first one to finish, before doing its stuff.". It seems to me that it should be "If two threads receive two messages with the same "id" from the same sender, the second thread has to wait for the first one to finish, before doing its stuff." ??? In either case, will update this accordingly.

Comment: Hello, sorry it took me so long to reply. Unfortunately I'm afraid this could not work, because it could happen that: 
 - thread 1 gets a message with ID 1;
 - thread 2 gets a message with ID 1; 
 - thread 2 gets the Object with id 1 and locks it;
 - thread 2 doesLotOfStuff() and then unlocks the Object with ID1;
 - thread 1 gets the Object with id 1 and locks it;
 - thread 1 doesLotOfStuff() and then unlocks the Object with ID1;

So the order would not be respected.

Answer (score 0):

You could get *some* speedup if you split up the JSON parsing from the `doLotsOfStuff()`.  One thread listens for messages, parses them, then puts the parsed message on a Queue to maintain chronological order.  A second thread reads from that Queue and doesLotsOfStuff with no need for locking.

However, since you apparently need more than a 2X speedup this is probably insufficient.

**Added**

Another possibility is multiple HashMaps.  For example, if all the IDs are ints, make 10 HashMaps for IDs ending with 0,1,2...  Incoming messages get directed to one of 10 threads, which parse the JSON and update their relevant Map.  Order is maintained within each Map, and there are no locking or contention issues.  Assuming the message IDs are randomly distributed this yields up to a 10x speedup, though there is one extra layer of overhead to get at your Map.  e.g.

```
Thread JSON                     Threads 0-9
--------------------------------------------------------------
while (notInterrupted) {
   read / parse next JSON message
   mapToUse = ID % 10
   pass JSON to that Thread's queue
}
                                while (notInterrupted) {
                                   take JSON off queue
                                   // I'm the only one with writing to Map#N
                                   do computation and update ID
                                }
```

Comment: Hello, sorry if it took me so long to reply. Eventually, I ended up implementing a variation of the two solutions you proposed. Unfortunately I can't implement the second, since the IDs that I'm receiving are too numerous and of different types. So I'm taking the last byte of the ID (which is an alphanumerical ASCII sequence) and I'm doing `thread_that_has_to_deal_with_this_message = last_byte_of_the_ID % number_of_parser_threads`

Comment: user949300 I finally did some testing today. Actually it works even better, I can handle 30k messages per minute, as opposed to the previous version with 20k. I think the considerable speedup is due to the fact that only one thread is reading directly from the input file, and to the fact that I don't have anything to synchronize anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Actually here is a design idea: when a consumer takes a request to work on your Object it should actually remove the object with that ID from your list of Objects and then re-insert it back once the processing is done. Then any other consumer getting request to work on the object with the same id should be in blocking mode waiting for the object with that ID to re-appear in your list. You will need to add a management to keep record of all existing objects so when you can distinguish between the object that exists already but is not currently in the list (i.e. being processed by some other consumer) and the object that does not exist yet.

Comment: Hello, sorry it took me so long to reply. Unfortunately the IDs that I'm receiving are too numerous and of different types; therefore I don't know in advance when and how many objects with a specific ID will arrive. Currently, when an object with a new ID arrives, i add it to the collection, so that I can have several thousands of objects with random IDs at a time.